# CollapsiblePanelExtender: Can not get object in onLoad of page

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm aware this might be a repeated question, but it's not

I already looked at this one

[CollapsiblePanelExtender: Can not get object in onLoad of page (AJAX Toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536810/collapsiblepanelextender-can-not-get-object-in-onload-of-page-ajax-toolkit)

I had tried the following load functions in order to achieve my goal

```
window.onload = setExtenderEvents;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setExtenderEvents, false);
window.addEventListener('load', setExtenderEvents, false)
document.body.onload = setExtenderEvents;
```

[image]

So, I'm getting a null. Of course, after I keep on executing this error and everything loads fine, I'm able to get the extender object

[image]

Any idea how can I achieve this. In chrome, and firefox, setting the event listener to load works perfectly. IE10 it's the one giving me a awful time and no, **I can't use any framework. I am allowed to use only pure vanilla js**

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to add an event too early.

Try using `Sys.Application.add_load` event:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
    var cpeDemo = $find('searchCollapse');
    cpeDemo.add_collapsing( ... );
}
```